Error in .find_candidate_solvers(object, solver = solver, gp = gp)
I am trying to estimate a constrained poisson regression model in which beta parameter is constrained to be positive using CVXR. It is "passing" CVX's DCP test, but when I try to find a solution, I get the following error:
Error in .find_candidate_solvers(object, solver = solver, gp = gp) :
The solver new("IneqConstraint", lhs = new("Variable", dim = c(1, 1), name = "varNA", value = NA, .is_vector = TRUE, nonneg = FALSE, nonpos = FALSE, complex = FALSE, imag = FALSE, symmetric = FALSE, diag = FALSE, PSD = FALSE, NSD = FALSE, hermitian = FALSE, boolean = FALSE, integer = FALSE, sparsity = numeric(0), pos = FALSE, neg = FALSE, attributes = list(nonneg = FALSE, nonpos = FALSE, pos = FALSE, neg = FALSE, complex = FALSE, imag = FALSE, symmetric = FALSE, diag = FALSE, PSD = FALSE, NSD = FALSE, hermitian = FALSE,
boolean = FALSE, integer = FALSE, sparsity = numeric(0)), boolean_idx = numeric(0), integer_idx = numeric(0), id = 810, args = list(), validate = TRUE), rhs = new("Constant", value = 0, sparse = FALSE, imag = NA, nonneg = NA, nonpos = NA, symm = NA, herm = NA, eigvals = NA, .is_vector = TRUE, .cached_is_pos = NA, dim = c(1, 1), complex = FALSE, symmetric = FALSE, diag = FALSE, PSD = FALSE, NSD = FALSE, hermitian = FALSE, boolean = FALSE, integer = FALSE, s
Further, when I try to estimate the model using MOSEK, it appears to be ignoring the constraint.
Here is a reproducible example:
set.seed(12421)
x <- rnorm(1000)
x <- x[x > 0.1]
y <- rpois(length(x), x)
alpha <- Variable(1)
beta1 <- Variable(1)
constraint <- list(beta1 <= 0)
prob <- Problem(Maximize(sum(y * (x %*% beta1 + alpha) - exp(x %*% beta1 + alpha))))
result <- solve(prob, constraint)
result$getValue(beta1)
result <- solve(prob, constraint, solver = "MOSEK")
result$getValue(beta1)

I've tried to estimate the model with and without specifying the solver and none can successfully estimate it.

This is an exponential cone problem so only MOSEK and ECOS will be applicable at all, I think. I cannot run CVXR code easily so please post the full Mosek log output and the actual values you get and explain why you think they are wrong and then I can try to help with Mosek. There is no such concept as a solver ignoring a constraint, but see https://docs.mosek.com/latest/faq/faq.html#why-does-the-solution-slightly-violate-constraints

Thanks for the quick reply. I found the error. I was placing the constraint in the wrong place when I was calling the solver.
